# Which one would be preferable here, Present Perfect or Present Perfect Continuous?

Tags: present-perfect, perfect-constructions, perfect-aspect

Sentences:

> 1. Here you're! We have just talked about you.
> 2. Here you're! We have just been talking about you.

I think I made a little mistake when I chose to use Present Perfect instead of Present Perfect Continuos. Boiling down to the rules the have no meaningfull diference except for emphasis on number (Present Perfect) and emphasis on duration (Present Perfect Continuos) IN GENERAL. I'm not talking about experience, personal changes, annoyance, and so forth.

But in this case we have past action of some duration which took place before the object of the conversation came. So the second one is more preferable, isn't it?

Comment: The second one is more preferable, but you should say "here you are" instead of "here you're"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second one is preferable because it indicates to the person (about whom you had been talking about) that while you were talking about him, he appeared. The first one, on the other hand, tells us that you were talking about him a while ago, switched to talking about another topic and then he appeared.